# Transform column to row data in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, unpivot

Eg :
#Oracle

Sample data :

| ID | A_ID | B_ID | C_ID | D_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'ABC' | 'XYZ' | 'PLO' | 'QWE' |

Expected Output :

| ID | A_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'ABC' |
| 1 | 'XYZ' |
| 1 | 'PLO' |
| 1 | 'QWE' |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the unpivot clause](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#CHDJBHHI):

```
select id, a_id
from your_table
unpivot (a_id for orig_id in (a_id, b_id, c_id, d_id))
```

| ID | A_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC |
| 1 | XYZ |
| 1 | PLO |
| 1 | QWE |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6UcM_Z6i)

The operation creates an extra column, which I've called `orig_id`, which can be used to identify which of the original columns a given value came from. I've excluded it from the select list, but the fiddle includes a version that shows it. You can also change the value that appears, by adding `as '...'` to each column name in the `in ()` clause.

You can read more about pivoting and unpivoting [in this article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1).